# invoking ios app with calendar event

Tags: ios, objective-c, mobile, calendar

I'm making Alarm clock app for an iPhone. Can anyone tell me if there any way to start some installed app within calendar event when it is invoked programmatically?
I want to set an alarm (event in iPhone calendar) from my app and when time comes my event occurs and should start my app. Well something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer, no. You cannot hijack the Calendar app's notifications.

You can however use [Local Notifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW13) to present an alert like the calendar app does at a specific time, the user can then choose to view the alert and be taken to your app.

Another option, albeit kludgy, is adding a link to your application in the calendar entry's notes or some other field. Something like myapp://event/123456, the user would have to know to touch this URI to open your app though.